# I wanted 'else' case to work only after they uncheck all the feilds,how can i approach?

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have selected 4 checkbox, if i uncheck one checkbox,its going to 'else' condition. But i wanted it to go to else condition only after i unchecked all the feilds. How can i approach this. Here is my code
.html

```
 <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let product of DisplayProductList">
                                    <label class="form-check-label text-break">
                                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [value]="product.template_name"
                                  [(ngModel)]="product.isChecked" (change)="changeSelection($event)"> {{ product.template_name }}
                                  <span class="form-check-sign">
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                  </span>
                                </label>
                                </div>
```

.ts

```
 changeSelection(event: any) {
    debugger;
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((product, index) => {

        if (product.isChecked == true) {
         return product.isChecked
 }
      }
      )
    } else {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.ProductData;
    }
```

Hope i will get solution here. Thank you

Comment: Please use https://stackblitz.com to upload the code, so that it will be easy for a reviewer to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement is checking 'event.target.checked', which is checking the current event that it is checked or unchecked. If you uncheck a checkbox, that 'uncheck' is the current event and 'event.target.checked' will be 'false'. I will suggest you do something like below

```
    changeSelection(event: any){
      for(i = 0; i < this.DisplayProductList.length; i++){
        if(this.DisplayProductList[i].isChecked == true){
          this.checked = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      
      if(this.checked){
       // if block
      }
      else{
       // else block
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank u I tried your code below but didnt work.
changeSelection(event: any) {
   var i;
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((product, index) => {

        for(i = 0; i < this.DisplayProductList.length; i++){
          if(this.DisplayProductList[i].isChecked == true){
            this.checked = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if(this.checked){
          return product.isChecked
         }
         else{
          this.selectedItemsList = this.ProductData;
         }
      }
      )
    }

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to run the ***ELSE*** when all checkboxes are unchecked is you need to remove else and change it into an ***IF*** first. Next, you need to put a condition to check the array ***DisplayProductList*** if all ***isChecked*** ***properties*** are *false*.

See below code:

```
changeSelection(event: any) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter(
        (product, index) => {
          if (product.isChecked == true) {
            return product.isChecked;
          }
        }
      );
    }
    if (this.DisplayProductList.every((el) => el.isChecked === false)) {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.ProductData;
    }
}
```

Notice inside the if condition, I'm using `every` and then I'm checking every object with `isChecked` properties if `false`. This will only return `true` if all `isChecked` properties inside `DisplayProductList` are false.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but didn't work, can you check

changeSelection(event: any) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((product, index) => {

        if (product.isChecked) {
      
          this.sendclusteridApi()
          return product.isChecked

        }
       
      }
      )
    } if (this.DisplayProductList.every((el) => el.isChecked === false)) {
      this.selectedItemsList = this.ProductData;
    }
   
 
  }

Comment: Thank you for your response,I have tried, But didnt work Dom

Comment: It used to be like, when i uncheck 1 checkbox out of 4, it goes to else case, now its not even going there, means, when i uncheck its not returning selectedItemlist.wish i could share my screenshot, but i am not able to,

Comment: Yes that should be correct because as per your question, you want the else to only run when all checkboxes are unchecked, that is why it won't return productData as long as there is a single checkbox that is checked

Comment: I checked in stackblitz and it is working fine.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrqomb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yeah As you said, When i check i want to return checked values and  I want 'else' to only run when all the checkboxes are unchecked, But its not going there even though I unchecked all boxes. tried with your solution.

Comment: can you check the stackblitz link I sent? I added the code there so that you can see how I used it.

Comment: Okay , Sure, I am looking at it, thank you

Comment: Let me know when you have some questions.

Comment: tried ur stblitz code When I uncheck my checkbox,somehow its not going to that condition.
 changeSelection(event: any) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
     this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((product, index) => {
            if (product.isChecked) {
 return product.isChecked
 }
           
          }
          )
        } 
        if (this.DisplayProductList.every(el => el.isChecked === false)) {
          this.selectedItemsList = this.ProductData;
         // console.log('TEST');
        }

Comment: Then you need to check the value in your DisplayProductList variable if all isChecked properties have value or is the isChecked property is not missing.

Comment: Instead of , I don't want to show anything. Like when i check it returns checked value, else it shoudlnt show anything,after i uncheck, how can i do that..?

Comment: I think you need to create a new question if you are changing the requirement.

Comment: Okay @dom.macs. Thank you for your prompt response, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you can just create a get and check simple if there is a true value in the list like this: `isChecked(): boolean { return this.DisplayProductionList.some(x => x.checked); }`

Now you can use this get property in your if - else block.